# Flutter TextField hint text not aligned center horizontally

Tags: flutter

I have a very simple `TextField`, where I have `textAlign: TextAlign.center` inside (as advised in other answer here).
However, hint text is not horizontally centered, whereas input text is centered. (see attached picture)
I wonder why.. Somebody please help.[image]

Code:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
  child: TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: 'time',
    ),
  ),
  width: 80,
)
```

Comment: Please copy and paste your code and put your image below, so that we can easily test your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use hintText instead of labelText:

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0),
  child: TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      hintText: 'time', //instead of labelText
    ),
  ),
  width: 80,
)
```